# sed/gsed "invalid command code . ", "expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `.' "

Tags: sed, zsh, macos

I get these similar errors in both OS X sed and gsed, in a command file that does not contain a period in expression 1, character 1. The only place a '.' appears in the file is on line 5, where it is escaped.

The command file is as follows:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/gsed -E
/^\s+/ d                        #trim leading spaces
/^$/ d                          #kill blank lines
s/([a-z])\n/\1 /                #unwrap text
s/([\.,;:]) (\w)/\1\r\2/        #CR at flow punctuation
```

Not sure where to go from here. Both OS X sed and gsed choke in the same way, whether run as a shell script or reading the command file with -f.
I've been through several other questions, on SE and other places, about errors of the format "unknown command: `.' "
In those cases the character quoted in the error message was in the wrong place, or often the -i command on Mac OS X needed an argument, but I'm not using the -i option.

Comment: I think your shebang should be `#!/usr/local/bin/gsed -Ef` ? Presumably you are executing this as something like `somecommand | ./sedscript`, and it looks like in that case `./somescript` gets interpreted as an expression, instead of *the name of a file from which to read* expressions.

Comment: @steeldriver It seems like you say. [From Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)): *"For example, if a script is named with the path path/to/script, and it starts with the line #!/bin/sh, then the program loader is instructed to run the program /bin/sh, passing path/to/script as the first argument"*. The same error will happen if you just run `sed .foo`, being `.foo` just an arbitrary string.

Comment: [edit] your question to provide concise, testable sample input and expected output so we can best help you. Without that we're guessing at what you want to do by reading code that doesn't do whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> #!/usr/local/bin/gsed -E
> ```

Should be:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/gsed -Ef
```

As you want `sed -Ef /path/to/the/sed-script other arguments` to be run when running `sed-script other arguments`, not <strike>`sed -E /path/to/the/sed-script other arguments`</strike> where `/path/to/the/sed-script` would be taken as the sed code to interpret.

> ```
> /^\s+/ d                        #trim leading spaces
> ```

No, that `d`eletes the current line if it starts with one or more characters classified as whitespace. To remove those characters and keep the line, it should be:

```
 s/^\s+//
```

Or the standard equivalent:

```
 s/^[[:space:]]+//
```

> ```
>  s/([a-z])\n/\1 /                #unwrap text
> ```

`sed` processes one line at a time with the *pattern space* containing the *contents* of those line, not including the line delimiter, so that can never match as the pattern space won't contain newline characters.

Also beware that what characters `[a-z]` matches is often random and subject to locale.

> ```
>  s/([\.,;:]) (\w)/\1\r\2/        #CR at flow punctuation
> ```

Beware `[\.,;:]` also matches on backslash. If you want to match on `,;:` only, it's `[,;:]`. You also likely want to substitute *all* occurrences on the line for which you need the `g` flag.

Here sounds you want:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
while (<<>>) { # reads one line into $_, includes the line delimiter
  s/^\s+//; # \n is also a \s so empty lines would be stripped in the process
  s/[a-z]\K\n//;
  s/([:;,]) +(\w)/\1\r\2/g;
  print;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like sed is the wrong tool for unwrapping hard-wrapped lines, at the very least.

I'm amused that you suggest perl, as many times in the past I have tried to do something in sed only to get frustrated and do it in a perl one-liner. :P